# How to change an object's material or texture with python script in blender game and for it to be visible?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have tried this with the materials:
[image]

```
import bpy

D = bpy.data

D.objects['Cube'].material_slots[0].material = D.materials['Material.001']

# material slot 0 is a material that is applied to the object.
```

But the effect is only visible "out of the game"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bpy` is the main blender module, it is not available inside the game engine where you should start your scripts with `import bge`. In the game engine you use different data structures than the main part of blender. I don't think the bge let's you easily change materials, [this page](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_2/bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.html) makes it sound like you need to loop over every poly to change the material.

There is a simple way to achieve what you want, using logic bricks to swap mesh objects. First step is to check you have the material linked to the data not the object, data is the default setting so may already be set.

[image]

Then duplicating the object and giving the second one the other material. Then you can use an Edit Object actuator to swap meshes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy
#For use with blender game before start.

print("running OPACITY_REDUCE.PY")
CurrentMaterialName = '666001'
mat = bpy.data.materials.get(CurrentMaterialName)
mat.use_transparency = True        
bpy.context.object.show_transparent = True  
mat.transparency_method = 'Z_TRANSPARENCY'
print("reducing alpha setting.")
bpy.data.materials[CurrentMaterialName].alpha -= 0.1
```

the script is done in bpy and won't work in the game engine, however you can use this to reduce the transparency, and bake it then use logic bricks as an action to use it in the game engine. Unfortunately I do not believe there is a way to use the bge module to reduce transparency, I have yet to find a way to do this in Blenders game engine but I'd look into this guys code for changing the texture; https://github.com/Kiva-Entertainment/yohk/blob/master/script/dynamicMaterial.py